# C# WPF DataGrid - ExpandoObject in loop

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, expandoobject

I have some problem with that code. What am I doing wrong?

```
List<dynamic> list = new List<dynamic>();
var columnBind = columnBindName(); // {id, n0, n1, etc...} Name of Columns Bind

list.Add(new ExpandoObject());

foreach (var c in columnBind)
{
    list[0].c = "something";    //not working in Datagrid
    Console.Write(list[0].c);   //in console i have "something"
    list[0].id = "hello";       //working in Datagrid
}
```

Comment: What do you mean _not working in DataGrid_? `list[0].c` is a different `c` then the one in your loop if that's what you mean. Your object will have 2 properties `c` and `id`

Comment: so there is option to repleace `c` for proporties from `columnBind` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to set property names defined in custom list and that `columnBindName` is some sort of `string` enumerable you can use feature that [`ExpandoObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx) implements `IDictionary<string, object>` interface which allows you to get/set property value by string name

```
foreach (var c in columnBind)
{
    (list[0] as IDictionary<string, object>)[c] = "property value";
}
```